# How to allow only specific credential for project in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, user-roles

I need to prevent using credentials by every projects. I.e. **test1** project should be able to access only **test1-cred** and only if it is started by **user1** from Gitlab or directly in Jenkins. Also this should be supported by Jenkins declarative pipeline. If you use specific credentials in **Jenkinsfile** which are not allowed for current project - Jenkins shouldn't allow to use them.

How can I implement such a behavior?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are three common places to configure credentials in Jenkins: by user, by folder or globally

It seems that the [folder plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-folder) would suit your use case. It allows to organize your projects in folders. For each folder you can configure access rights and credentials.

More informations on credentials: https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials